# TypeORM - ORDER by number of ORs matched

Tags: mysql, query-builder, typeorm

I need a bit of help with TypeORM.

#### What I have:

I have a query which search in VIDEO table by video name with multiple likes. My query looks like:

```
  async findAllByName(searchTerm: string, take: number, skip: number): Promise<Video[]> {    
    const query = this.videoRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('video')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('video.channel', 'channel')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('video.language', 'language')
        .take(take)
        .skip(skip)
        .orderBy('video.publishedAt', 'DESC');
    searchTerm.split(' ').forEach((term, index) => {      
      index === 0 ? query.where("video.name like :term", { term:`%${term}%` }) : query.orWhere("video.name like :term", { term:`%${term}%` });
    })
    return query.getMany();
 }
```

#### What I need:

As you can see in code I split search term by space and search for each word individually with `OR`. So this will match too many results I need to `ORDER` them based on how many `ORs` it match.

So if I would simplify my query a bit this would be my SQL atm:

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE video.name LIKE '%topspeed%' OR video.name LIKE '%audi%' OR video.name LIKE '%A7%' ORDER BY video.publishedAt';
```

and I need something like SQL below but written in TypeORM:

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE video.name LIKE '%topspeed%' OR video.name LIKE '%audi%' OR video.name LIKE '%A7%' ORDER BY (video.name LIKE '%topspeed%') + (video.name LIKE '%audi%') + (video.name LIKE '%A7%') DESC, video.publishedAt;
```

In terms of results my current query return something like this:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| id | name                  |  publishedAt  |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
|  5 | topspeed of audi Q8   |   15-03-2020  |
|  4 | Do you like audi?     |   14-03-2020  |
|  1 | My best audi          |   13-03-2020  |
|  3 | audi A7 topspeed      |   12-03-2020  |
|  2 | topspeed of mustang?  |   11-03-2020  |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

and I need it to return something like this:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| id | name                  |  publishedAt  |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
|  3 | audi A7 topspeed      |   12-03-2020  | #1th contains 3 search words
|  5 | topspeed of audi Q8   |   15-03-2020  | #2nd contains 2 words
|  4 | Do you like audi A7?  |   14-03-2020  | #3rd contains 2 words but pubshedAt is older
|  1 | My best audi          |   13-03-2020  | #4th contains 1 word
|  2 | topspeed of mustang?  |   11-03-2020  | #5th contains 1 word
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

#### What I tried:

I was digging around this topic for a while and only option I found was to use native query with something like:

```
manager.query(`My SQL comes here`);
```

but this is not ideal solution for me as searchTerm is comming from user so I need a prepared statement ideally. Is there any other way how this is accessibble? Please at least point me at right direction so I can look more.

Answer (score 0):

> and I need something like SQL below but written in TypeORM:
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM video 
> WHERE video.name LIKE '%topspeed%' 
>   OR video.name LIKE '%audi%' 
>   OR video.name LIKE '%A7%' 
> ORDER BY (video.name LIKE '%topspeed%') + (video.name LIKE '%audi%') + (video.name LIKE '%A7%') DESC, video.publishedAt;
> ```

---

```sql
SELECT *, (video.name LIKE '%topspeed%') + (video.name LIKE '%audi%') + (video.name LIKE '%A7%') AS terms_found 
FROM video
HAVING terms_found /* > 0 */
ORDER BY terms_found DESC, video.publishedAt;
```

Sorry, I cannot convert this to TypeORM code because of zero skills.

---

PS. This code does not take into account that some keyword may present in the value more than once - multi-presence is treated as single presence.

If you need to prioritize multi-presence, then you must calculate the amount of tokens instead of single presence checking. For this purposes use an expression like

```
(LENGTH(video.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(video.name, 'keyword', ''))) / LENGTH('keyword')
```

instead single `(video.name LIKE 'keyword')`.